# Determine if __array_wrap__ on ndarray subclass is called from unary ufunc or binary ufunc

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to tell if a ndarray subclass's [`__array_wrap__`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs) is called with a unary function or a binary function? (another [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.__array_wrap__))

Comment: +1 for a question that isn't related to keeping track of a card game or some other such nonsense

Comment: @bernie -- ha ha.  I'm having a real fun time trying to unravel the numpy data model to the point where I understand it well enough to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer:

The arguments to the ufunc are passed in as a tuple to `context`.  The form is:

```
(ufunc, ufunc_args, ufunc_domain)
```

You can check the length of `ufunc_args` to see if you got 1 argument or 2.  As a side note, I have *no idea* what `ufunc_domain` is (in my tests, it always seems to be `0`)...

```
import numpy as np
class Tester(np.ndarray):
    def __array_wrap__(self,output,context=None):
        print context[0].__name__,'is binary' if len(context[1]) > 1 else 'is unary'
        return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(self,output,context)

a = np.zeros(10)
b = a.view(Tester)
print (type(b))

-b
np.sqrt(b)
b+b
```

I suppose this is how you can tell `__array_wrap__` whether it is a binary or unary ufunc.  Unfortunately, when I asked the question in the beginning, I was hoping to know if this ufunc call was the result of a *unary operator*.  I didn't think of things like `np.abs` and `np.sqrt` as `unary` functions.

Comment: Can't you simply check if `context[0]` is one of the unary ufuncs you want to do something special with?

Comment: @Jaime -- Yeah.  Ultimately, although maintaining a set of functions seems fragile for a general case.  Actually, I decided that currently, I only want `negative` and `positive` to be special so I decided to deal with then in `__neg__` and `__pos__`, but I'm still interested in the question in general.  Still looking to see if someone else has a better idea (or knows what `ufunc_domain` actually is useful for).

Comment: ufunc domain is the argument that you are (or I guess the one that is wrapping, not sure if you get output/input argument depending on which function is called wrap or prepare). Maybe more interesting for `__array_prepare__`.

Comment: @seberg -- i'm sorry. . . I don't follow your comment.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: try `np.modf` it has multiple out arguments.